# How can I create my own methods which take a block as an argument and which I can call later?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, block

How can I create my own methods which take a block as an argument and which I can call later?

I have tried following things.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
typedef void (^viewCreator)(void);

@interface blocks2ViewController : UIViewController
{
}
-(void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator *)block;

@end


- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self createButtonUsingBlocks:^(NSString * name) {
        UIButton *dummyButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100)];
        dummyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview:dummyButton];
  }];
}

-(void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator *)block
{
    //    Do something
    NSLog(@"inside creator");
}
```

I have also tried to pass the block variable to my custom method but without any success. Why it is so and what is the right way to do this?

---

**Update**

This is file `is.h`:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (^viewCreator)(void);

@interface blocks2ViewController : UIViewController
{

}
- (void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator)block;
@end
```

And this is the `.m` file:

```
#import "blocks2ViewController.h"

@implementation blocks2ViewController
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        [self createButtonUsingBlocks:^(NSString * name) {
        UIButton *dummyButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100)];
        dummyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview:dummyButton];
        [dummyButton release];
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

// ...

-(void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator)block
{
//    viewCreator;
    NSLog(@"inside creator");
}
@end
```

Comment: Please *add* updates instead of changing the original question and check the formatting in the preview *before* posting.

Comment: The update still has the problem with the typedef - change `typedef void (^viewCreator)(void);` to `typedef void (^viewCreator)(NSString*);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First** the `typedef` is off if you want to let your blocks take a string parameter:

```
typedef void (^viewCreator)(NSString*);
```

**Secondly** the type for blocks is:

```
ReturnType (^)(ParameterTypes...)
```

and not

```
ReturnType (^*)(ParameterTypes...)
```

Thus there is no need to add pointers to the `viewCreator` type:

```
- (void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator)block;
```

**Third** you actually have to call the block if you are not doing that yet:

```
-(void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator *)block {
    block(@"button name");
    // ...
```

**Fourth** and last, the `UIButton` is over-retained - you should `release` or `autorelease` it:

```
UIButton *dummyButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:...];
// ...    
[self.view addSubview:dummyButton];
[dummyButton release];
```

**Throwing** all that together:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
typedef void (^viewCreator)(NSString*);

@interface blocks2ViewController : UIViewController {}
-(void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator)block;      
@end

@implementation blocks2ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    [self createButtonUsingBlocks:^(NSString *name) {
        UIButton *dummyButton = 
            [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100)];
        dummyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview:dummyButton];
        [dummyButton release];
    }];
}

-(void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator)block {
    block(@"my button name");
}
@end
```

Comment: @Ajay: See the edit, are you actually calling the block somewhere?

Comment: Awesome answer.  One additional note;  if your goal is to store the block and call it later, you need to `copy` the block.  Blocks start out on the stack and very bad things will happen if to call a block that wasn't copied after the declaring stack frame has been destroyed.

Comment: OK now that i have commented typedef statement and since i am using block as inline function(i am actualy calling createButtonUsingBlocks:,which in turn takes that block as an argument)So i need not to copy ot,right?But still there seems some error...It will be nice if you can just post few lines in which a custom method takes block as argument and use it later on.This will make a more clearer picture..

Comment: @Ajay: What is some error? And what do you mean with later on? Just passing a block to a method and calling it in there? With the code structured as in your question, if you call the block in `-createButtonUsingBlocks:` there is no problem. By the way, Mike Ash had a good post on [block basics](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html).

Comment: ot's a very smaal code and it gives error in those lines where i have declared the -createButtonUsingBlocks: and where i have defined -createButtonUsingBlocks: I am sure it's syntectical error,that's why i wanted you to send few lines sothat i knowwhere i am wrong..Error reads    expected ')' before 'viewCreator'

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface blocks2ViewController : UIViewController {
 
  
 
 
}
- (void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(viewCreator)block;






@end

sorry for any silly mistake..

Comment: @Ajay: You are now missing the `typedef void (^viewCreator)(NSString*);` before your interface declaration.

Comment: but you said it's off when my block takes any parameter

Comment: specifically if the argumnt happens to be NSString

Comment: @Ajay: With it being off i meant the `typedef` was wrong and has to be changed, not to remove it. See the edit.

Comment: and after writing typedef there is an error in my viewDidLoad saying   error: incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^)(struct NSString *)', expected 'viewCreator'       My viewDidLoad looks like this

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  [self createButtonUsingBlocks:^(NSString * name) {
  UIButton *dummyButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100)];
  dummyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  [self.view addSubview:dummyButton];
  [dummyButton release];
 }
  ];
}

Comment: @Ajay: Compare your version with what i added above. If that doesn't help add your current code to the question or into PasteBin or similar.

Comment: sorry george,it's now working but i could not know the reson.Why it's not working when i am declaring it in .h file...Should i take it as a way to use methods taking block or what?

Comment: Thanks a lot george.It wasthe best way i could have learnt how to create our custom methods using blocks.Thanks for everything.

Comment: @bbum: yes you should copy it but you also need to know when to release it

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it this way without pre-defining the method:

```
@interface blocks2ViewController : UIViewController
-(void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(void (^)(NSString *name))block;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createButtonUsingBlocks:^(NSString * name) {
        UIButton *dummyButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100)];
        dummyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.view addSubview:dummyButton];
    }];
}

-(void)createButtonUsingBlocks:(void (^)(NSString *name))block
{
    block(@"My Name Here");
}
```