# Calling Objective-C method with block argument

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

how can to call this:

```
-(BOOL)setCloudEnabledAndOverwriteCloudWithLocalIfConfirmed:(void (^)(void (^setConfirmationAnswer)(BOOL answer)))confirmationBlock
```

Thanks.

Massimo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create my own methods which take a block as an argument and which I can call later?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674490/how-can-i-create-my-own-methods-which-take-a-block-as-an-argument-and-which-i-ca)

Comment: You should read an introductory-level Objective-C tutorial.

Comment: It's okay to ask that.. it's a block parameter that gets passed a block. can be confusing if you're not an experienced obj c programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BOOL someResult = [instance setCloudEnabledAndOverwriteCloudWithLocalIfConfirmed:^(void(^setConfirmationAnswer)(BOOL answer)){
    // do something if needed
    setConfirmationAnswer(YES);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[object setCloudEnabledAndOverwriteCloudWithLocalIfConfirmed:^(BOOL answer){
/* do your stuff here */
}];
```